# Вывод комбинаций чисел вида XXXX-XXXX из массива [0-9]

Tags: php

Не понимаю, как это сделать. 
Додумался только до array_rand. Но это не то.

Дан массив $array = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]

Нужно, чтобы при каждом выполнении генерировалось 10 строк со случайными комбинациями вида XXXX-XXXX так, чтобы первая часть XXXX не была равна второй XXXX, а так же не равнялась XXXX-XXXX предыдущему XXXX-XXXX

Comment: Ни хрена не понять... Во-первых, при чём тут тег SQL. Во-вторых, нужны все возможные комбинации? или только несколько? если второе - то случайные или как? Цифры в результате повторяться могут или нет? В общем ни разу не продуманная задача.

Comment: Это две несвязанные задачи. Решите сперва одну, первую. Рекомендую 1) додумать формулировку и откорректировать вопрос 2) удалить тег [sql].

Comment: Отредактировал, объяснил, как смог

Comment: *10 строк со случайными комбинациями вида XXXX-XXXX так, чтобы первая часть XXXX не была равна второй XXXX* Комбинация "0000-1111" - устраивает?

Comment: Каждая цифра - случайная

Comment: Вы на вопрос ответить можете? всего-то и делов - сказать "да" или "нет". А если нет - то ещё неплохо бы добавить "потому, что".

Comment: Нет, не устраивает, нужно что-то типа этого: 0368-2159

Comment: а зачем тут массив чисел с 0 до 9? рандомьте 4х значное число 2 раза делайте свои преобразования и проверяйте условием, что вам нужно

Comment: *не устраивает* ПОЧЕМУ??? потому что все цифры должны быть различными? или по какой-то иной причине? PS. Слушайте, уже надоедает тащить из Вас информацию клещами по кусочкам...

Comment: Не устраивает потому, что цифры д.б. рандомные.

Comment: *цифры д.б. рандомные* Из набора цифр при рандомном выборе с вероятностью 0.01% можно получить четыре нуля подряд. Следовательно, группа "0000" может быть поручена рандомно и причины её отвергать - нет.

Comment: Хорошо, я Вас понял. Как решить задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Как решить задачу?*

Один из вариантов - собирать в цикле уникальные числа в массив, разбивать массив на подмассивы и объединять элементы подмассивов в строку через разделилель "-":

```
$numbers = [];

while (count($numbers) < 20) {
    $numb = str_pad(mt_rand(0, 9999), 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $numbers[$numb] = $numb;
}

list($a, $b) = array_chunk($numbers, 10);
$numbers = array_map(function($a, $b){ return "$a-$b"; }, $a, $b);

var_dump( $numbers );
```

Comment: Спасибо, но есть код проще, без функций?

Comment: @astlin без функций код будет гораздо сложнее, а не проще ) Тут всего-то две функции, куда уж проще?

Comment: в результатах не попадается цифра 0 первым символом

Comment: ладно, это все не то,  буду разбираться дальше, спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @astlin "_в результатах не попадается цифра 0 первым символом_" - я подкорректировал свой пример.